# Changing value of dropdown on website via vba script

Tags: html, vba, excel

Currently trying to select a different value in a dropdown menu on a website through the use of a VBA macro. I do not believe the index method will work (the majority of similar questions on here have been answered with that), since the order of the options in the dropdown will be changing. HTML code is below, I'm trying to select one of the options included (doesn't matter which one, it just needs to be specific to one based on the "value"). Thanks for any help!

```
    <select id="storePickupOptions" ng-model="selectedPickupStore" ng-options="storeDescription(pickupStore) for pickupStore in onlineShoppingStores track by pickupStore.recordId" ng-required="true" mobile-friendly-select-options="true" class="ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" required="required"><option value="01600273" label="60 Worthington Mall, Worthington, OH 43085 (2.03 miles)" selected="selected">60 Worthington Mall, Worthington, OH 43085 (2.03 miles)</option><option value="01600818" label="2090 Crown Plaza Dr., Columbus, OH 43235 (2.68 miles)">2090 Crown Plaza Dr., Columbus, OH 43235 (2.68 miles)</option>t Street, Troy, OH 45373 (61.91 miles)">731 W. Market Street, Troy, OH 45373 (61.91 miles)</option></select>


<option value="01600273" label="60 Worthington Mall, Worthington, OH 43085 (2.03 miles)" selected="selected">60 Worthington Mall, Worthington, OH 43085 (2.03 miles)</option>
<option value="01600818" label="2090 Crown Plaza Dr., Columbus, OH 43235 (2.68 miles)">2090 Crown Plaza Dr., Columbus, OH 43235 (2.68 miles)</option>
<option value="01600805" label="6417 Columbus Pike, Lewis Center, OH 43035 (7.18 miles)">6417 Columbus Pike, Lewis Center, OH 43035 (7.18 miles)</option>
```

Sorry for the messy code, it's due to a lot of revisions trying to get this to work, but the VBA is below.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = True

Dim rngURL As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim MyURL As String
Dim Rows As Long, links As Variant, IE As InternetExplorer, link As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim sID As String
Dim rngLinks As Range, rngLink As Range


Dim filterRange As Range
Dim copyRange As Range

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

Rows = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rngLinks = ws1.Range("E2:E" & Rows)
i = 2

With IE
    .Visible = True


        .navigate ("https://www.kroger.com/account/update")

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:006"))

                Dim doc As Object
                Set doc = IE.document


            doc.getElementById("storePickupOptions").Value = "01600818"


End With





Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

ws1.Activate

Set rngLinks = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Something like ie.document.getelementbyid("storepickupoptions").value = "01600805"?

Comment: Hmm I tried inserting that, but I get a object required error. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Let's see the rest of your code. Sounds like an object isn't initialized. Also, if possible post the website being used.

Comment: I think it was the capitalization of the ID reference. I fixed that and no longer get the error, however it doesn't change the selected store. I'll get the code in here in a second,

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the code. Basically I removed variables that weren't used, and combined a few lines. Based on looking at the HTML provided, this should change the value of the dropdown.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateWeb()
    Dim ws1             As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ie              As New InternetExplorer
    Dim rows            As Long: rows = ws1.Cells(ws1.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rngLinks        As Range: Set rngLinks = ws1.Range("E2:E" & rows)

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate ("https://www.kroger.com/account/update")
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        Wend
        'It appears this element is only available when you've logged in
        .document.getElementById("storePickupOptions").Value = "01600818"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ryan, you're correct in that the options are only available when logged in. Unfortunately, this isn't changing the drop down, although I don't get an error from it.

Comment: try giving the element focus first `.document.getElementById("storePickupOptions").focus`. What value is the element after running the code? e.g. try printing `debug.print .document.getElementById("storePickupOptions").Value`

Comment: Hmm, I tried inserting the .Focus command above the the .Value command, but I'm still not seeing the dropdown change. The debug.print didn't yield a value either.